# Regex to check pattern with numbers

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to create a regex that does the following

`<\numberMAX8>[space or not]<\symbol(-)>[space or not]<\numberMAX8>` and max 10 times of all of this - I don't care about end spaces, also numbers must be between 5-8.

To explain it a bit more I'll give a few examples

ex:

> 5-6 7-6 8-8 6-7 ok
>
> 4-7 not ok //because of 4
>
> 7    -   6 ok
>
> 7-6-6-6 not ok because of the `-` in the middle

Below is what I have so far without having included the mid spaces.

```
^([5-8](?:-|\s)[5-8][\s]){1,10}
          ->  <-//didnt work.
```

Comment: Can you add all possible input formats with their validity

Comment: Maybe `^[5-8] ?- ?[5-8](?: [5-8] ?- ?[5-8]){0,9} *$`

Comment: Try using this: `^(?:[5-8]{0,8}\s*-\s*[5-8]{0,8}\s*){0,10}$`

Comment: I can add more examples, yes, but I think the are sufficient, could you please be more specific as to perhaps what you dont understand. The regex I have included at the end, is more or less what I want.

Comment: What is not clear is how these values are separated one from the other. Whitespace? Try [`^([5-8]\s*-\s*[5-8]\s*){1,10}$`](https://regex101.com/r/GhwOIs/1).

Comment: Try [`^([5-8]\s*-\s*[5-8]\s*){1,10}$`](https://regex101.com/r/y5Xusu/1)

Comment: They can be separated with or without whitespace, Let me try them

Comment: Yeah, `\s*` matches 0+ whitespaces.

Comment: Okay all of them worked I tested real quick. I'll wait a bit and accept the 'best' solution, Thank you!

Comment: @nonerth I think you should test more properly. My regex will refuse `6-76-76-7` while Wiktors and Tushars will accept it. From your latest comment it seems this is a valid sample, so I'd guess mine is not working correctly.

Comment: Go to regex101.com and play with it until you got it. What makes you think you need a look-ahead anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
^([5-8]\s*-\s*[5-8]\s*){1,10}$
```

So the explanation is:

The regex matches a starting number from 5-8 `^[5-8]`, then an arbitrary number of spaces `\s*`, then dash `-`, then arbitrary number of spaces `\s*`, then a number from 5 to 8 `[5-8]`, then an arbitrary number of spaces `\s*`, and that pattern from 1 to 10 times `{1,10}`, and nothing after the pattern `$`.